# Why property ID's not match to correct tile ID's?

Tags: xml, tmx, tiled

When i add properties to my tiles the properties get mapped to `tileID - 1`. I know a 0 means an empty tile on the `<layer data>`. This confused me for quite some time until I noticed it. The obvious fix is to just increase the property by 1 when parsing the file. But does anyone has an idea why this is? Am i missing something or is this even normal behaviour?

*Example*

- I gave the floor tiles a test property floor.
- I gave two walls a collision property PassableXXXX.

Here is part of my TMX:

```
  <tile id="0">
   <properties>
    <property name="floor" value="floor"/>
   </properties>
  </tile>
  <tile id="1">
   <properties>
    <property name="PassableNorth" value="0"/>
   </properties>
  </tile>
  <tile id="2">
   <properties>
    <property name="PassableEast" value="0"/>
   </properties>
  </tile>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Floor" width="8" height="8">
  <data encoding="csv">
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
</data>
 </layer>
 <layer name="Wall" width="8" height="8">
  <data encoding="csv">
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,3,3,5,3,0,0,
0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
</data>
 </layer>
```

As you can see, the 0 property is mapped to the empty tiles of the wall layer. GID 2 and 3 are my actual north and east wall but are referred as 1 and 2 in the properties section.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML snippets leaves out a relevant property on the `tileset` element, namely `firstgid="1"`.

A map can have several tilesets, so the tiles used on a map are referenced using global IDs that span all these tilesets. In contrast, the tile definitions inside the `tileset` element use local tile IDs. The offset between these is defined by the `firstgid` attribute, which stands for "first global id" since it is the global id that references the first tile in the tileset.

More details about this can be found at https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format#data

Comment: I'm still not sure why this is. Would it not be better to just use the GID on the properties as well? Now i have to calculate which tileset to use and then calculate back if the property belongs to this tileset.

Comment: This is not possible, since tilesets can also be stored externally and used by multiple maps. For each map, the mapping of global ID to the local tile IDs in the tileset can be different.

Comment: Didn't realize your the developer of tiled. Very good job, although not perfectly suitable for my implementation. I had another short question: Is it already possible to load tile by tile within the LibGDX TmxLoader? This is because i need to sort depth by tile (even within) on isometric maps. I'm already writing my own parser though :)

Comment: I am not familiar with the LibGDX TMX support classes. It sounds like you would only want to customize the rendering though and not the parsing, if it is about drawing order.